# Is there a method in Magento that allows to create MySQL triggers and stored procedures?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-enterprise, mysql, mysql-triggers

I am trying to find out if Magento has a method available that allows to create MySQL triggers and **Stored Procedures**.

Currently, i am using the core resource DB adapter to insert the raw SQL directly from my setup script, and was wondering if there was in fact a method available for this, similar to the way we add foreign keys, etc.

Does anyone know of anything like this either in EE or CE? A library or custom script perhaps?

Answer (score 5):

Ok, so i haven't had much response from this so started digging around myself am able to answer half of the question i asked.

Did a simple "grep" and came across the following class tucked away in the lib folder: `lib/Magento/Db/Sql/Trigger.php`

Its pretty straight forward and here is what i have come up with that does work (can be placed in your install/ upgrade script):

```
<?php
/** @var $installer Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup */
$installer = $this;
$installer->startSetup();

// Trigger
$trigger = new Magento_Db_Sql_Trigger();

// Set time SQL_TIME_BEFORE / SQL_TIME_AFTER
$trigger->setTime($trigger::SQL_TIME_BEFORE);

// Set time SQL_EVENT_INSERT / SQL_EVENT_UPDATE / SQL_EVENT_DELETE
$trigger->setEvent($trigger::SQL_EVENT_INSERT);

// Set target table name
$trigger->setTarget($installer->getTable('fontera_trader/leaderboards_global_tmp'));

// Set Body
$trigger->setBody(
'INSERT INTO '.$installer->getTable('fontera_trader/leaderboards_global').'
    (entity_id, customer_id , credit_value, prize_value, games_played, rank, prev_rank)
    VALUES
    (NEW.entity_id, NEW.customer_id, NEW.credit_value, NEW.prize_value, NEW.games_played, NEW.rank, NEW.prev_rank)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
    customer_id = NEW.customer_id,
    credit_value = NEW.credit_value,
    prize_value = NEW.prize_value,
    games_played = NEW.games_played,
    rank = NEW.rank,
    prev_rank = NEW.prev_rank;

    SET @r = 0;

    UPDATE '.$installer->getTable('fontera_trader/leaderboards_global').'
    SET
    prev_rank = rank,
    rank = @r:= (@r+1)
    ORDER BY
    credit_value
    DESC;
'
);

// Assemble query, returns direct SQL for trigger
$triggerCreateQuery = $trigger->assemble();

// Adapter initiates query
$this->getConnection()->query($triggerCreateQuery);

$installer->endSetup();
```

I have added comments to give a basic idea of what can be used, else best go check the class out yourself. The body is basically raw SQL but can be compiled using Magento's conventional methods. I have used raw SQL for demonstration purposes.

That out of the way, i am still trying to find a way to implement **STORED PROCEDURES** without success. Has anyone come across anything like this in Magento that may be tucked away for future use?

Comment: The easiest route is just use a `.sql` version file with your stored procedure. More details: http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources

Comment: In addition and to avoid errors, you can specify a trigger name with `$trigger->setName('my_trigger_name')` and add `$this->getConnection()->dropTrigger($trigger->getName())` just before `$this->getConnection()->query($triggerCreateQuery);`